# problem with jquery Toggle

Tags: jquery

I need small help with jquery.

EDIT:

```
    echo "<li> ";
        echo $navi_menu->navi_name;
         echo "<ul>";
```

and the Jquery to it was,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#nav li:has(ul)").click(function (event) {
                    if (this == event.target) {
                        $(this).toggleClass('clicked').children('ul').slideToggle();
                        $(this).find('li:has(ul)').removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp();
                        $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp();
                    }
                }).addClass('has_ul');

            });
        </script>
```

This used to toggle up and down...now i have added a href tag in my html, instead of printing naviname(echo $navi_menu->navi_name;
) directly, i want a link to it. I need help to rewrite the jquery to accomdate a href wherever li tag comes....

```
   echo "<li> ";
        echo "<a class=\"click\" href=\"display_mod.php?navi_id=".$navi_menu->navi_id."\">$navi_menu->navi_name</a>";
           switch($navi_menu->navi_id) {
            case 1:
                echo "<ul>";
```

and the jquery to it was,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#nav li:has(a.click):has(ul)").click(function (event) {
                    if (this == event.target) {
                        $(this).toggleClass('clicked').children('ul').slideToggle();
                        $(this).find('li:has(a.click):has(ul)').removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp();
                        $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked').find("ul").slideUp();
                    }
                }).addClass('has_ul');

            });
        </script>
```

With the modifed jquery to accomdate a href tag is not working.

Here li tag is parent and ul is child and the chain continues.

(Part of the code is from cssplay.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is: `$('#nav li:has(a.click)')` if you want to check if the `li` has an `a` with class `click` as child.

Comment: what is the exact problem now?

Comment: but how should this work at all, if your `a` will link to another page?

Comment: hard to judge without a complete source code. could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: No, it was no link I could reach.

Comment: this link works, but as i said, your links are the problem. if you click on the folder icon everything works fine, but if you click on a link you are forwarded to a new page. On this page all folders are open, but fold by clicking on the icon. I don't get what you want to achieve, sry.

Answer (score 1):

Since the link isn't a parent or child of the ul, it looks like you just want to make it an additional constraint. Just add another `has()` to it?

```
$("#nav li:has(ul):has(a.click)").click(function (event) {
```

If you mean you want to now target the link itself then just use a space instead of a has method.

```
$("#nav li:has(ul) a.click").click(function (event) {
```

If this isn't what you're looking for you'll have to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: +1, Hi Tesserex, Thanks for ur reply. It is helpful. I have edited my question. Now i want the same toggle up and down functionality, with a href tag in it..i tried the above and till far no luck..

Comment: @lucky Which exact elements do you want to toggle up and down? The li? The a and the ul but not the li? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you. Give it a try.

```
$("#nav li:has(a.click, ul)").click(function (event) {
  //Your other statements here.
});
```